# fail Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state

Tags: javascript, http, websocket, get

there:
I am want to send some data

here is the code :    filename:[wx-resource.ts]

```
import {Promise} from 'es6-promise';
declare const wx: any;
class WxResource {
  public socketOpen: boolean = false;
  public count: number = 0;
  public socketState;

  public reqObj: any = {
    url: 'http://192.168.8.138/api/v1/user/auth/status',
    token: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0ODcxMjg0MjcsImxldmVsIjoiIiwidWlkIjoiZTE3MmQ0NGUtZGY5Ni00NzBjLTlmM2QtMWJkN2RlNjU3MTA0In0.BG2w-Lo02i2xaga4iZkM7RmP8hXgpRKAC-0MTp5hFj_ugnwATt2m9nDjtmJfRpWnAlpfmXZLgEQTlMHwG2H9hhoqojJC6piCh76UkH0mNwjJrBGiTINurholwTF2VYQPysB4bz7G4jepzEccNdD_NW-_Rxw-Bo5WDcH37OZ2zTw"
  };

  constructor() {
    this.listen().connect().afterConnect();
  }

  private listen(): WxResource {
    let _that = this;

    wx.onSocketOpen((event) => {
      console.info('WebSocket已打开：', event);
      this.count++;
      this.socketState = event.target.readyState;
      this.socketOpen = true;
      // this.sendMsg(_that.reqObj,"GET");
      console.log("open的次数：", this.count);
      return this.socketOpen;
    });
    wx.onSocketError((event) => {
      console.error('WebSocket连接打开失败，请检查！', event);
    });
    // console.log("外部：", this.socketOpen);
    return this;
  }

  private connect(): WxResource {
    wx.connectSocket({
      url: "ws://192.168.8.138/api/ws"
    });
    return this;
  }

  private afterConnect(resolve?, reject?): WxResource {
    wx.onSocketMessage((res) => {
      console.log("服务器返回：", JSON.parse(res.data));
      resolve(JSON.parse(res.data));
    });
    return this;
  }

  //发送消息
  private sendMsg(reqObj, method?) {
    console.log("socketState: ", this.socketState); //undefined
    if (!this.socketOpen) {
      console.log("webSocket opened");
      // 判断是否传入token
      let header = {};
      if (reqObj.token === undefined) {
        console.log("no token");
        header = {
          "S-Request-Id": Date.now() + Math.random().toString(20).substr(2, 6)
        }
      } else if (reqObj.token !== undefined) {
        console.log("get token");
        header = {
          "S-Request-Id": Date.now() + Math.random().toString(20).substr(2, 6),
          "Authentication": "Bearer " + reqObj.token
        }
      }
      wx.sendSocketMessage({
        data: JSON.stringify({
          "method": method,
          "url": reqObj.url,
          "header": header,
          "body": JSON.stringify(reqObj.data)
        }),
        success: function (res) {
          console.log("发送成功", res)
        },
        fail: function (res) {
          console.log("发送失败", res)
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("socket not open", this.socketOpen);
    }
  }

  public get() {
    let _that = this;

    console.log("socketOpen", this.socketOpen);
    this.sendMsg(this.reqObj, "GET");


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      _that.afterConnect(resolve, reject);
    })
  }

}

export default WxResource;
```

then I'm import above code like this:

```
import WxResource from '../../utils/wx-resource'
```

and use it

```
const wxResource = new WxResource();
wxResource.get();
```

and something went wrong:
here is the console:

```
"sendSocketMessage:fail Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state."
```

I just want to call wx.onSocketOpen (), and then by calling the get method when using wx.sendSocketMessage to send data to the server,method POST, DELETE the same, without calling wx.onSocketOpen () again; I don't know where is wrong, please point out, thank you